# unable to connect to my android phone

Tags: 18.04, android, mtp

I am trying to connect to my phone with android.  Seems to have to do with [Media Transfer Protocol](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp) (MTP).

```
$ mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.13

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 2, dev 12
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

The computer correctly identifies my phone as a Samsung Galaxy yet fails to connect.  Could it be that my Android phone has the problem?

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema I resolved this problem another way, by removing the SD Card from my phone and connecting to my laptop directly.  Now Ubuntu reads this information through a different drive.  Also quite fast!

Comment: @johnmangual If you try my way, you won't have to physically connect the phone to the computer, and you can probably still have your SD card.

Answer (score 2):

Try `GSConnect` on your Ubuntu box [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/), and `KDE Connect` on your phone [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp).

`GSConnect` is a complete implementation of KDE Connect especially for GNOME Shell with Nautilus, Chrome and Firefox integration. It does not rely on the KDE Connect desktop application and will not work with it installed.

`KDE Connect` allows devices to securely share content like notifications or files and other features like SMS messaging and remote control. The KDE Connect team has applications for Linux, BSD, Android, Sailfish and Windows.

`KDE Connect Indicator` can support Gtk desktops other than GNOME Shell.

`Installation Docs` are [here](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki/Installation#standard)

Comment: Awesome! I've been scratching my head for days with far more involved process to do this.